# How to know if a server have private networking enabled or not

Tags: ubuntu

How can I know if my server (ubuntu 16.4) have private networking enabled or not? is there a command or something I could check with it?

Comment: Ask the network administrator or hosting provider? Check the server's IPs with `ifconfig`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with private you mean any of the network classes designated for private IP addressing you can check it with `ip addr` command or `ifconfig`. If any of the network adapters has an IP address of the classes then you have private networking.